# I'm trying to find the average of 3 scores which I ask the user to input

Tags: javascript, mean

I'm trying to understand why my input of scores1, scores2, and scores3
 are taken as a string. Ex: score1 =1, score2 = 1, score3= 1. Avg score 
 is calculated as 111/3 and not 3/3..

```
  player1 = prompt(" Welcome Player 1! Please Enter your name ");
  alert(" Hello, " + player1+".");


  p1score1 = prompt(' Enter first score. ');
  p1score2 = prompt(' Enter second score. ');
  p1score3 = prompt(' Enter third score. ');

  /*p1score1 = 89;
  p1score2 = 120;
  p1score3 = 103;
  */

  p1avgScore = (p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3)/3;

  console.log(" Congratulations " + player1 + ". Your scores are: " + 
  p1score1 + ", " + p1score2 + ", " + p1score3 + ".");
  console.log(" Your average score of all three games are: " + 
  p1avgScore);
```

---

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `prompt()` function [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Return_value), rather than a number which causes `(p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3)` to produce a concatenation of strings `p1score1`, `p1score2` and `p1score3`, rather than to perform arthimentic (ie addition) of all to a sum total.

Consider the following adjustment with `parseFloat()` added to resolve this:

```
p1score1 = parseFloat( prompt(' Enter first score. ') );
p1score2 = parseFloat( prompt(' Enter second score. ') );
p1score3 = parseFloat( prompt(' Enter third score. ') );
```

By doing this, the result of each `prompt()` is parsed to a number which means the value types for `p1score1`, etc, are `number`. This now means that addition will be performed on this line, rather that string concatenation:

```
(p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3)/3
```

Hope that helps!

```js
var player1 = prompt(" Welcome Player 1! Please Enter your name ");
alert(" Hello, " + player1 + ".");


var p1score1 = parseFloat(prompt(' Enter first score. '));
var p1score2 = parseFloat(prompt(' Enter second score. '));
var p1score3 = parseFloat(prompt(' Enter third score. '));

var p1avgScore = (p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3) / 3;

console.log(" Congratulations " + player1 + ". Your scores are: " +
  p1score1 + ", " + p1score2 + ", " + p1score3 + ".");
console.log(" Your average score of all three games are: " +
  p1avgScore);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse your input in integer/float.

```js
player1 = prompt(" Welcome Player 1! Please Enter your name ");
  alert(" Hello, " + player1+".");


  p1score1 = parseInt(prompt(' Enter first score. '));
  p1score2 = parseInt(prompt(' Enter second score. '));
  p1score3 = parseInt(prompt(' Enter third score. '));

  /*p1score1 = 89;
  p1score2 = 120;
  p1score3 = 103;
  */

  p1avgScore = (p1score1 + p1score2 + p1score3)/3;

  console.log(" Congratulations " + player1 + ". Your scores are: " + 
  p1score1 + ", " + p1score2 + ", " + p1score3 + ".");
  console.log(" Your average score of all three games are: " + 
  p1avgScore);
```

Comment: Hi @Hamza Abbasi, you're answer is perfect but for you're information you can use Number function as well which is also work as parseInt. For ex. parseInt(2) = Number(2)